# Free up storage space after VACUUM ANALYZE

Tags: sql, postgresql, vacuum

I need to free up the storage space after `VACUUM ANALYZE` is executed.
I know that there's `VACUUM FULL` but the problem with this is, it locks the table which might cause problems (if there are on going transactions).

Is there any other way to free up the space to the operating system?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, `vacuum full` is the only (built-in) option for that. You could try [pg_repack](https://reorg.github.io/pg_repack/) if you don't mind installing and using external tools

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I understand. I’m currently looking into autovacuum right now if the solution of my problem is there. :)

Comment: Autovacuum works exactly like a manual `vacuum` - it does not release space to the filesystem. It just marks the space as re-usable for subsequent new rows.

Comment: Thanks again! I guess pg_repack is my only option. haha.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @a_horse_with_no_name! 
You could use pg_repack extension for Postgres.